# Convert number into words using flex

Tags: apache-flex, numbers, words, numericstepper

I am trying to convert an entry using a numeric stepper in flex into words to display in a textarea.

i.e a user uses the stepper to enter "89" as a value and in the text area the words "Eighty nine" are displayed.

After much searching i haven't found anything that helps - a few javascript functions but that is all.

any help sample code would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript and ActionScript are the same language.  You can use the JavaScript one or at the very least update it to be fully AS3 compliant and use it.

Comment: That's not really accurate. They're very similar, both based on ECMA script, but it is easy to convert javascript into actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make a hash table with the numbers "0" to "99" as indices (enclosed in quotes) and the values being the word names for those numbers. That will make localization possible without out a lot of complicated code to determine, for example, the difference between "eleven" and "juu ichi" (`ten one`) in Japanese or between "ninety-nine" and "quatre vingt dix neuf" (*eighty-nineteen*) in French, "twenty-two" and "zwei und zwanzig" (two and twenty) in German, etc.

Let's name that hash table `myNumberWords`. Then you would simply convert your digits as follows:

```
function getWordsFromNumber(num:Number) : String {
  return myNumberWords[num.toString()]; 
}
```

If you want to go higher than 99, add a hash for the words *hundred*, *thousand*, *million*, *billion*, etc., then split your whole number into an array and place the appropriate units after every 3rd number, counting from the top of the stack. You'll also have to have zero values and double-zero values counted as empty strings ("") except when there is only one digit and it is a zero, etc.